# Why would a URL ending in .com be a security threat?

Tags: security, wordpress

I have a WordPress website hosted on Pagely.

When I searched for a string ending in `.com`, it triggered a security threat warning and my site was blocked. I raised an issue, but I got the following answer:

> Yes, any URL string ending in a .com triggers our security as it could possibly be harmful. I understand yours is not but that's how our security is setup.

Given that most popular web sites have domain names ending in `.com`, why would a URL ending in `.com` be classified as potentially harmful?

Comment: You'd probably have better luck on IT Security

Comment: Sounds like F.U.D. to me..

Answer (score 3):

Wild guess (you should be asking Pagely why they deem it's a risk to get the actual answer), it's probably because .com is a file extension that's used by windows for some types of executables.  My hunch is that they don't want people hosting malicious files on their service and this is one method they're using to keep them out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the concern is that `.com` is a holdover executable extension on Windows from the good 'ol DOS days, just like `.exe` is executable. The folks doing the filtering don't want end users to save executable files from the Internet for concern that they may be malicious files. See "[Difference between .com, .exe, and .bat?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2115651/difference-between-com-exe-and-bat)" on StackOverflow.

Comment: I just tried to searching for a string ending in .exe and no problem. So far, it's just .com.

Comment: It could be that they don't trigger on .exe, for whatever reason.

Comment: @Brajeshwar Then I guess they suppose that since `.com` is a holdover and `.exe` is contemporary that `.exe` can be legitimate. Just for grins, have you tried searching for `.net`?